# How to delete many occurrences of a symbol within comments in an XML file in R, delete the symbol and save it back to XML with the original name?

Tags: r, xml, xslt, xml-parsing

I need to delete several occurrences of a symbol (single quote) within comments in an XML file in R, and then save it back to XML. I have to do this in 1000s of XML file.

In each XML file the single quote appears more than 50 times and present in different child hierrachial structure (some in child and some in sub-child). But always present within the comments.

I Tried using XML package in R. I first tried to enable this one XML file, but didn't know how to proceed further.

```
    library(XML);library(xml2);library(methods);library(tidyverse)
#Read one XML file
filepath <- "C:/Users/PeriaPr/Desktop/repex1.xml"
onefile <- xmlTreeParse(gsub("'","",readLines(filepath)),asText = TRUE)
xmlroot <- xmlRoot(onefile)
var <- xmlSApply(xmlroot, function(x) xmlSApply(x, xmlValue))
```

Here is a reproducible example of my XML file. The single quotes (around Orange, Apple and Banana) need to be removed in this multiple tree hierarchical structure. The quotes occur almost 50 times within one XML file, and I need to process (delete single quotes) 1000s of XML files

```
<?xml version = "1.0" encoding = "windows-1252"?><document id="myrepex.xml">
<action_step step_no="1.3.1.1">
    <step>1</step>
    <title><![CDATA[Part1 - 'Apple']]></title>
    <start><![CDATA[2019/08/09 7:57:17]]></start>
    <duration><![CDATA[0 Hr. 12 Min. 22 Sec.]]></duration>
    <status><![CDATA[Passed]]></status>
</action_step>
<action_step step_no="1.4.1.1">
    <step>2</step>
    <title><![CDATA[Part2 - 'Orange']]></title>
    <start><![CDATA[2019/08/09 8:09:39]]></start>
    <duration><![CDATA[0 Hr. 32 Min. 55 Sec.]]></duration>
    <status><![CDATA[Passed]]></status>
</action_step>  
<action_step step_no="1.5.1.1">
    <step>68</step>
    <title><![CDATA[Part3 - 'Banana']]></title>
    <start><![CDATA[2019/08/09 8:42:35]]></start>
    <duration><![CDATA[0 Hr. 36 Min. 28 Sec.]]></duration>
    <status><![CDATA[Passed]]></status>
</action_step>
<action_step2 secondchild="secondchild">
    <action_step2subchild subchild="subchild">
        <title><![CDATA[Part3 - 'Banana']]></title>
    </action_step2subchild>
</action_step2>
```

Comment: You have tagged the question "R" and "XSLT", but your question only mentions "R". Is an XSLT solution acceptable?

Comment: Your question talks about "comments" but there are no comments in your XML. Did you mean CDATA sections?

Comment: @MichaelKay Thanks for your quick response. Much appreciated. I like to do this using the XML package since looping to multiple files is very easy within the XML package. But I will certainly try the XSLT way that you have suggested. Yes, I meant to say CDATA sections and not comments. I need to retain the CDATA tagging as such after deleting the quotes.

Comment: @MichaelKay: Tried. See some errors. I'm brand new to XSLT and as such to XML world. Pasting here my code and XSL file and the error message. Can you see what am I missing?  <br/>     #using XSLT
doc <- read_xml("C:/Users/PeriaPr/Desktop/repex1.xml", package = "xslt")
style <- read_xml("C:/Users/PeriaPr/Desktop/repex1xsl.xsl", package = "xslt")
new_xml <- xml_xslt(doc, style)

Comment: @MichaelKay Error message I see: Error in doc_xslt_apply(doc$doc, stylesheet$doc, paramstr) : 
  xslt error: compilation error: file /Desktop/repex1xsl.xsl line 2 element mod.

Comment: @MichaelKay #contents inside repex1xsl.xsl `code`<xsl:transform version="3.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>
  <xsl:output method="xml" cdata-section-elements="title"/>
  <xsl:template match="title/text()">{translate(.,"'","")}</xsl:template>
</xsl:transform>

Comment: I strongly suspect you are using an XSLT processor that does not support XSLT 3.0. I used XSLT 3.0 in my solution for brevity, but if you're prepared to write 20 lines of code rather than 4, it can be done easily enough in XSLT 1.0.

Answer (score 2):

To delete all single quotes in the content of title elements, you can use the following XSLT 3.0 stylesheet:

```
<xsl:transform version="3.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>
  <xsl:template match="title/text()">{translate(.,"'","")}</xsl:template>
</xsl:transform>
```

If you want to retain the CDATA tagging (which is considered by XSLT to be pure noise), add an `xsl:output` declaration with `cdata-section-elements` attribute.

To apply this transformation to many source XML files, you could either (a) use Saxon's ability to process all files in a directory from the command line, (b) put the control logic within the XSLT stylesheet (using the collection() function), or (c) use some external control logic, e.g. XProc, Ant, or a shell script.

Comment: Tried but seeing error. Provided the details in the comments section in my post. Would appreciate any insight

Comment: I strongly suspect you are using an XSLT processor that does not support XSLT 3.0. I used XSLT 3.0 in my solution for brevity, but if you're prepared to write 20 lines of code rather than 4, it can be done easily enough in XSLT 1.0. But XSLT 1.0 is very old and I'm out of the habit.

Answer (score 0):

Consider this XSLT 1.0 script and then iterate with R's `xslt` package (extension of `xml2`):

**XSLT** *(save as .xsl file to be read in R)*

```xml
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="no" indent="yes"
                             cdata-section-elements="title start duration status"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
     <xsl:copy>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
     </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    
   <xsl:variable name="single_quote">&apos;</xsl:variable>

    <xsl:template match="title">
     <xsl:copy>
       <xsl:value-of select="translate(., $single_quote, '')"/>
     </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

<kbd>[**Online Demo**](https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/asoTKL)</kbd>

**R**

```r
library(xml2)
library(xslt)

# RETRIEVE ALL XML FILES
setwd("C:/path/to/xml/files")
xmls <- list.files(pattern="xml")

# LOAD XSLT
style <- read_xml('C:/path/to/Script.xsl', package = "xslt")

# USER-DEFINED METHOD
proc_xml <- function(xml_file) {
    # LOAD XML AND XSLT
    doc <- read_xml(xml_file)
    
    # TRANSFORM XML
    new_xml <- xslt::xml_xslt(doc, style)

    # SAVE NEW XML (REMOVE paste0 TO OVERWRITE ORIGINAL XML)
    write_xml(new_xml, paste0("new_", xml_file))

    return(new_xml)
}

# ITERATE THROUGH XML FILES
new_xmls <- lapply(xmls, proc_xml)
```